# Javascript tree Node Codes

Tags: javascript

ı want to use this http://www.jstree.com/documentation/contextmenu

ı can create , delete ,edit nodes but my question is,
how can ı get created node's value or id
how can ı get deleted node's value or id 
because i will insert into database.
and here javascript codes

http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js

For Create Process i found this code probably this code belongs to create process under.

```
 // Basic operations: create
            create_node: function (obj, position, js, callback, is_loaded) {
                obj = this._get_node(obj);
                position = typeof position === "undefined" ? "last" : position;
                var d = $("<li />"),
                    s = this._get_settings().core,
                    tmp;

                if (obj !== -1 && !obj.length) { return false; }
                if (!is_loaded && !this._is_loaded(obj)) { this.load_node(obj, function () { this.create_node(obj, position, js, callback, true); }); return false; }

                this.__rollback();

                if (typeof js === "string") { js = { "data": js }; }
                if (!js) { js = {}; }
                if (js.attr) { d.attr(js.attr); }
                if (js.metadata) { d.data(js.metadata); }
                if (js.state) { d.addClass("jstree-" + js.state); }
                if (!js.data) { js.data = this._get_string("new_node"); }
                if (!$.isArray(js.data)) { tmp = js.data; js.data = []; js.data.push(tmp); }
                $.each(js.data, function (i, m) {
                    tmp = $("<a />");
                    if ($.isFunction(m)) { m = m.call(this, js); }
                    if (typeof m == "string") { tmp.attr('href', '#')[s.html_titles ? "html" : "text"](m); }
                    else {
                        if (!m.attr) { m.attr = {}; }
                        if (!m.attr.href) { m.attr.href = '#'; }
                        tmp.attr(m.attr)[s.html_titles ? "html" : "text"](m.title);
                        if (m.language) { tmp.addClass(m.language); }
                    }
                    tmp.prepend("<ins class='jstree-icon'>&#160;</ins>");
                    if (!m.icon && js.icon) { m.icon = js.icon; }
                    if (m.icon) {
                        if (m.icon.indexOf("/") === -1) { tmp.children("ins").addClass(m.icon); }
                        else { tmp.children("ins").css("background", "url('" + m.icon + "') center center no-repeat"); }
                    }
                    d.append(tmp);
                });
                d.prepend("<ins class='jstree-icon'>&#160;</ins>");
                if (obj === -1) {
                    obj = this.get_container();
                    if (position === "before") { position = "first"; }
                    if (position === "after") { position = "last"; }
                }
                switch (position) {
                    case "before": obj.before(d); tmp = this._get_parent(obj); break;
                    case "after": obj.after(d); tmp = this._get_parent(obj); break;
                    case "inside":
                    case "first":
                        if (!obj.children("ul").length) { obj.append("<ul />"); }
                        obj.children("ul").prepend(d);
                        tmp = obj;
                        break;
                    case "last":
                        if (!obj.children("ul").length) { obj.append("<ul />"); }
                        obj.children("ul").append(d);
                        tmp = obj;
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (!obj.children("ul").length) { obj.append("<ul />"); }
                        if (!position) { position = 0; }
                        tmp = obj.children("ul").children("li").eq(position);
                        if (tmp.length) { tmp.before(d); }
                        else { obj.children("ul").append(d); }
                        tmp = obj;
                        break;
                }
                if (tmp === -1 || tmp.get(0) === this.get_container().get(0)) { tmp = -1; }
                this.clean_node(tmp);
                this.__callback({ "obj": d, "parent": tmp });
                if (callback) { callback.call(this, d); }
                return d;
```

Comment: There is a [demo](http://www.jstree.com/demo), see the last one. It contains code for all operations you enumerated.

Comment: you mean , i can get value of created node and i can send it to my database ?

Comment: Last sample is _all_ about database interaction. It even called 'PHP & mySQL demo'

Comment: what do you mean by saying demo ?

Comment: Did you opened link I provided?

Comment: and can you give me simple example for inserting database with last sample ?

Comment: It's just a ajax post request to php hanlder. See line started with `.bind("create.jstree", function (e, data) {`

Comment: i can not use this tree node with c#?

Comment: Sorry? Client-side is javascript only. Server-side (part which implemented on php in demo) can be in any language you know: C#/VB/F#.net; php; node.js; Python; Ruby; etc.

Comment: thanks for help but i need also sort example binding to sql database with c# , can you give me any sample ?

Comment: Well. This is actually totally different question and there is _a lot_ of samples in net. Try to start with [this one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)

Comment: i know how to insert database.But i dont know how to get value from javascript and send it , this is my question sir

Comment: You need to create generic handler (.ashx) which will get requests form javascript (as it works in demo), do all work with database and response back to client javascript. Check [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/104/Many-ways-to-communicate-with-your-database-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASP.NET) starting from ashx section, or google it.

Comment: thanks for help i will research about what you say but it seems very hard for beginners and i can not give you point there is no arrow i dont know why

Comment: Because I don't posted answer, we discussed in comments and gone far from initial question. Good luck in your research.